# Data too big to be shown on mobile version of the graph

Tags: vue.js, charts, chart.js, vue-chartjs

I have a graph for 30 days data and when it scales to mobile it crashes, since there are too many xAxes.

I've tried with xAxes ticks, max, min etc.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please provide more information so that it is easier to provide meaningful answers. Post the code and different snippets of what you've already tried to fix the solution. You can also add a screenshot of the issue you are facing.

Comment: You need to post your code and representative data in order for us to reproduce your issue.